# Автоматическое "понижение" индекса в базе данных

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, django, sqlite

У меня есть небольшая база данных Sqlite с такими полями:

```
Ally_ID Name Age Class
```

Я заменил стандартный ID на Ally_ID. Предположим у меня есть 10 записей. Если я удалю первые 3 и добавлю новые 2 то Ally_ID будет иметь индекс с 4 по 12. Как сделать так чтобы записи уменьшали свой индекс, т.е 4-я запись стала 1-ой, а новые записи(11 и 12) стали 8 и 9?

Comment: А зачем вам понадобилось его уменьшать ? В 95% случаев желание уменьшить автоинкрементные id говорит о неправильном подходе к решению какой то прикладной задачи.

Comment: Мне не нужна большая база данных(У нее ограничение в 100) и с уменьшающимися автоинкрементными id будет легче работать в моем случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что название таблицы table и столбец Ally_ID является автоинкрементом.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `Ally_ID` INT(11); 
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY; 
UPDATE `table` SET `Ally_ID`='0'; 
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `Ally_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Для sqlite

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 0 WHERE name = "table"
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку Result: near "MODIFY": syntax error
At line 1:
ALTER TABLE `Allies` MODIFY.

Comment: @Denzel покажите Ваш пример запроса полностью.

Comment: Вот ALTER TABLE `Allies` MODIFY `Ally_ID` INT(11);

Comment: Старайтесь не путать ковычки. Насколько я понял, у Вас вся строка в одинарных ковычках. Используйте двойные "ALTER TABLE `Allies` MODIFY `Ally_ID` INT(11);" Или не используйте одинарные вообще "ALTER TABLE Allies MODIFY Ally_ID INT(11);" Иначе у Вас запрос обрезается от первой ковычки до следующей первой встречной.

Comment: Хмм. . . Я убрал ковычки, но все равно ошибка.

Comment: Покажите полный запрос, как Вы его вставляете в python. Прогнал у себя - всё работает.

Comment: Я его не в питон вставлял, а в SQLite. Второй день изучаю django даже не знаю куда здесь вставляются напрямую sql-запросы. Просто пользуюсь методами .save(), .delete() и тд.

Comment: дык, у sqlite'а вообще `ALTER TABLE * MODIFY` синтаксиса нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer оу, точно, я и позабыл. Спасибо за замечание.